# Mongodb doesn't update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I'm trying to update the profile user in my data in mongodb but it doesn't update, it doesn't return an error either in my console..

**here's my function:**

```
function editPassword(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/users/update`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            email: email,
            password: password1
        })
    })
    .then(res => {
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        if(data === true) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Account updated.",
                icon: "success",
            })
            Router.push('/')
        } else {
            Router.push('/error')
        }
    })
}
```

**This is the routes:**

```
router.put('/update', auth.verify, (req, res) => {
    UserController.editPassword(req.body)
    .then(resultFromUpdate => res.send(resultFromUpdate))
})
```

**This is the controllers:**

```
module.exports.editPassword = (params) => {
        const updates = {
            firstName: params.firstName,
            lastName: params.lastName,
            email: params.email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(params.password, 10)
        }

        return User.findByIdAndUpdate(params.userId, updates).then((updated, err) => {
            return (err) ? false : true
        })
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your connection is successful with the mongodb?

Comment: @UmairRiaz yes, it says "Now connected to mongodb atlas"

Comment: `User.findOneAndUpdate({userId: params.userId}, { $set: updates }, { new: true }).then((updated, err) => {return (err) ? false : true})`

Comment: @UmairRiaz thank you so much!! It's working now.. what do you think is my mistake on my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `findOneAndUpdate`
and use `$set` for the `patch` and `new` for returing updated payload.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({userId: params.userId}, { $set: updates }, { new: true })
  .then((updated, err) => {return (err) ? false : true})
```